# Conflicting types for function 'getline' in C Language

Tags: c

I am trying to run the following code, which searches for the longest line in a list of lines and copies/saves it.

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline);

void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }

    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);

    return 0;
}


int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i = 0;

    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

But the compiler says that there is an error with `getline` where there is a conflict in types.

So mainly `getline()` fetches for the longest line in the list of line by processing the number of chars in it.

Comment: Before asking please do at least a simple search about the warnig/error message! That took less time to find than opening a question.

Comment: BTW: corner bug in `getline(char s[],int lim)`.  Consider `getline(s,1)`, what happens with `if (c == '\n')`?  Better to use `int c == 0;`.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

It conflicts because you redefine the prototype for the original libc function `getline()` whose prototype is definied in `<stdio.h>`.

From `man 3 getline` we have:

`ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`

If you redefine it with `int getline(char line[], int maxline)` you are conflicting with the original `getline()` function.

Simply rename your function so that it does not conflict with the library.

Comment: There is no indication OP even includes a standard header, less if he uses a POSIX system. And - please - do at least a simple search for dupes.

Comment: You mean your _answer_, not question, I suppose?

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the improper 3rd party edits.

Comment: Your edit actually made it even worse. It now implies `getlione` is a standard C function. Which it apparently is not. That POSIX-part should have been a hint. The question is a dupe and subjet to be deleted anyway.

Comment: There is no "standard C function". There is only a language. There is a standard C library whose name is usually "libc". This standard C library can be written in any compiled language you want, could be assembler.

Comment: The C standard library is defined in the C standard ISO9899. WHich makes the functions part of the standard. "standard C function" refers to the standard and the expected ABI used by the application code. I never stated they have to be implemented in the C language themselves, as long they use the same C-ABI as the implementation used for the user-code (and provide the specified functionality). But thanks for detailing.